# Harmonic mean between two numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $2(y-a)$ is Harmonic mean between $y-x$ and $y-z$, then $x-a,y-a,z-a$ are in

$(A) AP$

$(B)HP$

$(C) GP$

$(D)$ None of these

I tried by using the formula $\frac{2ab}{a+b}$ but the equations are becoming way big for me to handle. Is there a trick for these questions or just simply calculation?

Comment: What is the source of this *algebra-precalculus* problem, @HydrousCaperilla?

Comment: It's in one of my practice textbook for sequence and series problems.I just noticed they have changed the question in the solution .Replacing x-a with z -a  as one of the terms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note:  This is only a partial answer.  I gave up after trying to check whether $x-a, y-a, x-a$ is in AP.)

The harmonic mean of $y-x$ and $y-z$ is
$$\frac{2(y-x)(y-z)}{2y-(x+z)}.$$

Setting this equal to $2(y-a)$, gives you
$$y-a=\frac{(y-x)(y-z)}{2y-(x+z)}.$$

Solving for $x$ in terms of $y$ gives
$$\bigg(2y-(x+z)\bigg)(y-a)=(y-x)(y-z)$$
$$2y^2 - y(x+z) - 2ay + a(x+z) = y^2 - y(x+z) + xz$$
$$y^2 - 2ay + a(x + z) - xz = 0$$
$$(a - z)x = - y^2 + 2ay - az$$
$$x = \frac{- y^2 + 2ay - az}{a - z}.$$

Subtracting $a$:
$$x - a = \frac{- y^2 + 2ay - az}{a - z} - a = \frac{(- y^2 + 2ay - az) - (a^2 - az)}{a - z} = \frac{- y^2 + 2ay - a^2}{a - z}.$$

This implies that we have
$$x - a = -\frac{(y - a)^2}{a - z}$$
$$y - a = \frac{(y-x)(y-z)}{2y-(x+z)}$$
$$x - a = -\frac{(y - a)^2}{a - z}.$$

**Question was edited to ask about $x-a, y-a, z-a$ instead.**

Note that we could rewrite
$$x - a = -\frac{(y - a)^2}{a - z}$$
$$y - a = \frac{(y-x)(y-z)}{2y-(x+z)}$$
$$x - a = -\frac{(y - a)^2}{a - z}.$$
as
$$x - a = \frac{(y - a)^2}{z - a}$$
$$y - a = \frac{(y-x)(y-z)}{2y-(x+z)}$$
$$z - a = \frac{(y - a)^2}{x - a}.$$

There should be a simple way to test whether this sequence of three terms is in AP, HP, or GP, but I am not seeing it.

Comment: Nice ! Re-arranging your results gives $(x-a)(z-a)=(y-a)^2$ which shows $x-a$, $y-a$ and $z-a$ are a geometric progression $k, \space kr, \space kr^2$.

Comment: Indeed!  Blimey, how could I miss such a simple fact... signs of aging... xD